# Is there a possibility to change the response time in Operational Analytic console IBM MobileFirst

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-analytics

Is there a possibility to change the response time in Operational Analytic  console  Or any of Network Activities properties that IBM Mobilefirst captures by it self on any network call from client.

I want to change these details from client app. (Android).

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by "response time"... of what?

Comment: I am asking about the response time that is shown on the operational console of IBM Mobilefirst console. Can I change the Value of that Response time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response time that is collected on the MobileFirst Operational Analytics Console is data collected from server. This response time is collected on a MobileFirst adapter call.

We do not allow you to change your response time because that would be manipulating your data.

This data is used to see if your response time is too low and allows you to take the appropriate action to speed it up, whether that be changing the payload size, enforcing use only when a good connection is made, etc.

Comment: I am seeing something called Roundtrip Time in the analytics console is this captured from client or server....  It is also captured for the service calls to other rest servers.

Comment: Round trip time is calculated from Client-->Server-->Adapter and then all the way back to the client. There should be another time called Backend time, that time is Server-->Adapter.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. what if i am using WLRequestResponse and directly connecting to server .. No Adapters at all.. will it still capture Client-->server ...Roundtrip time.... If not is there any other way i can capture this  data to custom chart..